# Displayed all user orders on my-account order history, but it warn me 'invalid order'. Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display all the order on the admin `order history` page (including order customers's order). So that the admin can view the orders on the front end.

And I am trying to modify the template - `my-order.php` to show the orders on this page. However, I displayed a list of all orders, but when I clicked into the order, it said that `Invalid order`(Which is not admin own order).

```
/**my-order.php**/
$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'wo<?php foreach ( $customer_orders  as $k => $v) :
            $order      = wc_get_order(  $customer_orders[ $k ]->ID );
            $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
            ?>
            <tr class="order">
                <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                        <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                        <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                            </a>
```

How do I display all the orders the order history?

Thanks for helping.